Remove scroll-bar when SVG exceeds containing element
Problem:

Solution:

I want to remove the scrollbar from SVG scaling. I Want my SVG path to flow over and under my text lines, and I want the SVG to be big enough to cover the width of my text properly that's why I am using scale property. And if I am using overflow then my SVG gets out of place.
SVG STYLE ::
.svg-container{
    margin-top: 45rem;
    z-index: -999;
    /* overflow-y:hidden; */
    }
svg{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    scale: 2;
    margin-left: 240px;
    background-size: cover;
}

SVG CODE ::
<div class="svg-container">
            <svg width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
                <path id="curvePath" d="M -50,120 Q 90,-60 190,110 Q 310,260 390,110  Q 480,-90 700,130" fill="transparent" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="20px"/>
                <text width="500" dy="5px">
                    <textPath href="#curvePath">
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe cum sit ipsam placeat consequatur nulla deleniti, tempore sapiente velit! Nam repellendus vel delectus exercitationem dolor tempore illum, sapiente vero porro.
                        <animate id="anim1" attributeName="startOffset"
               from="0" to="600"
               begin="0s;anim2.end" dur="5s"
               repeatCount="1"
             />
             <animate id="anim2" attributeName="startOffset"
                from="600" to ="0"
                begin="anim1.end" dur="5s"
                repeatCount="1"
             />
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-title-container">
            <div class="hero-title-first">I<i class="hero-title-first-n">n</i>novation</div>
            <div class="hero-title-second">& expertise</div>
        </div>



This is going to be very difficult. I highly recommend that you move the text into the SVG.
